# Update HTML on click event angular

Tags: angular

I want to update html on click event. With jquery it was very easy to do with `html()` method. but with angular I am little confused with it.

.ts file

```
  updateVideoId(videoId: string) {
    let html;
    html = `<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_${videoId} popover=false popoverAnimateThumbnail=true" style="display:inline-block;height:700px;position:relative;width:80%">nbsp;</span>`; 
  }
```

```
<mat-button (click)="updateHtml('asdfasd65f4823asdf')"></mat-button>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_8zc2rphave popover=false popoverAnimateThumbnail=true" style="display:inline-block;height:700px;position:relative;width:80%">nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

I simply want to update the html on click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I will use `[ngClass]`, because the only thing you change is the name of one of the classes of your span element. So modifying the entire html element is probably not usefull.

**ts file**

```
className: string = 'wistia_async_8zc2rphave';

updateHtml(videoId : string){
  this.className='wistia_async_'+videoId
}
```

**html file**

```
<mat-button (click)="updateHtml('asdfasd65f4823asdf')"></mat-button>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <span class="wistia_embed" [ngClass]="className" popover=false popoverAnimateThumbnail=true" style="display:inline-block;height:700px;position:relative;width:80%">nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

I have created a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r2dz1e?file=src/app/app.component.html) to show you an example of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put whole html into angular page:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" [innerHTML]="yourHtmlVariable"></div>
```

yourHtmlVariable - you can change it by click in your controller.
If you need just change your class:

```
<span [class]="yourClassName" style="display:inline-block;height:700px;position:relative;width:80%">nbsp;</span>
```

or use [ngClass] with conditions https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass